# Deployed SSIS package throwing error. Works fine in local

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dataflow, ssis-2014

I have to edit a SSIS package written by somebody else. On loading the package in Visual Studio I was getting error "Failed to decrypt protected XML node". I resolved this error by setting property Protection Level to "Do not Save Sensitive Data" at project and individual package(dtsx) level. I was able to build solution successfully after that without any errors and was able to execute the package as well successfully. Now upon deployment of this package to Server, when I try to run it form SQL Server Agent Job, I get below errors:
1) “The binary code for the script is not found”
2) The type or namespace is missing..., could not be found in ScriptMain.cs

Any idea on how it can be resolved will be helpful.

Comment: Seems that you have problematic script task inside one of the packages. Please, inspect erroneous package and post its script task C# code here.

Comment: Probably this is due to missing references inside the script task. As a side note, the error "Failed to decrypt protected XML node" usually is unharmfull and you should take no actions whatsoever

Comment: @rpd,@Ferdipux: the task is a Data Task Flow Plus which is problematic. But this task executes successfully on local environment. If any references were missing, it should have failed in local as well

Comment: So you re-deployed the package on the same server without changing anything on the said script task and now it throws this error? Additionally, do you have the same VS version / package version than the person who originally created it?

Comment: @rpd: Yes I did not change anything in the said Data Flow Task Plus, i added another dtsx which works fine both in local and deployed package. But the existing Data Flow Task Plus started failing in package after deployment. VS version which I used to make changes (adding new dtsx in same SSIS package) is higher than the VS version used for developing the original package

Comment: Is the script in place? Usually when using newer VS, scripts tend to clear and become empty. It happened to me couple of times

Comment: @rpd: yes its in place and I able to execute it successfully in my local (from Visual Studio), But on deployment when I execute it from SQLAgent, it fails with error "The binary code for the script is not found"

Comment: The maybe it is the other way around. If you upgraded the package on a newer version and the server is on older package version, you may need to downgrade it.